# Why does installing IPython need sudo even when using --user?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, ipython

I'm trying to install IPython like so:

```
pip install --user --src ~/pipsrc ipython
```

And I get this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/'
```

Why does pip want to install (some of?) IPython here?

**update:** after installation with `sudo`, there is still nothing in "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython" — so maybe it's a bug in the IPython installer?

Comment: First, this sounds more like a question for AskUbuntu or ServerFault. Second, which linux flavor are you using? Third, permission denied usually means that the user that you are using does not have access to the folder that you are editing; that is why you need sudo. What is your username? What are the permissions on /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython?

Comment: As @kingledion suggest, you probably don't have writing permissions in that directory. You should try using pip install --target "your path". Then, remember to add that directory to your PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Comment: Is IPython already installed in the Python installation at ``/usr/local``? You can have issues with using ``--user`` if package already installed in Python installation globally as it may want to remove the existing version if new one is a different version. Suggest you use a Python virtual environment instead.

Comment: @kingledion @Alejandro yes, of course I do not have writing permissions. I am wondering why pip wants them even though I specified `--user`.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Good thinking. No, it's not already installed. I'm installing this in a bare-bones VM dedicate to this single app, so I'm not using virtual environments.

Comment: Run it in verbose mode and see what it says it is doing.